# From FileInputStream to BufferedInputStream conversion

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

we were given a few exercises in lab and one of these is to convert the file transferring method from `FileInputStream` to `BufferedInputStream`. It's a client sending a GET request to a web server, which sends the file requested.
I came up with a simple solution, and I just wanted to check if it's correct.

Original code:

```
try { 
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(req);
      // req, String containing file name
      byte[] data = new byte [fis.available()]; 
      fis.read(data); 
      out.write(data); // OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){ 
      new PrintStream(out).println("404 Not Found"); 
    }
```

My try:

```
try { 
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream(req));
      byte[] data = new byte[4];

      while(bis.read(data) > -1) {
        out.write(data);
        data = new byte[4];
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){ 
      new PrintStream(out).println("404 Not Found"); 
    }
```

The file is a web page named index.html, which contains a simple html page.
I have to reallocate the array every time, because at the last execution of the while loop, if the file isn't a multiple of 4 in size, the data array will contain characters from the previous execution, which are shown in the browser.
I chose 4 as data size for debugging purposes.
Output is correct.

Is this a good solution or can I do better?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to re-create the byte array each time - just overwrite it. More importantly though, you have a conceptual mistake inside your loop. Each iteration just writes the array to the stream assuming it's all valid. If you examine [`BufferedInputStream#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-)'s documentation you'll see it may not read enough data to fill the entire array, and will return the number of bytes it actually read. You should use this number to limit the amount of bytes you're writing:

```
while((int len = bis.read(data)) > -1) {
    out.write(data, 0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you close off your file once you are done.  The BufferedInputStream uses an 8 KB buffer by default which you are reducing to a smaller buffer.  A simpler solution is to copy 8 KB at a time and not use the added buffer

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(req)) {
  byte[] data = new byte[8 << 10];
  for (int len; (len = bis.read(data)) > -1; ) 
      out.write(data, 0, len);
} catch (IOException e) { 
  out.write("404 Not Found\n".getBytes()); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. In the case of files stored on the hd, FileInputStream accesses the disk at every read operation, whereas BufferedInputStream won't ,making it more efficient, generally speaking. Is this the same when files are served over a network - which is my case now? Or is there basically no difference?

Comment: FileInputStream accesses teh OS on every read, the OS can use predictively read ahead and will only hit the disk every so often.  BufferedInputStream only helps if the blocks of data you read are much smaller, e.g. << 512 bytes, than the buffer it reads. i.e. it isn't magic, its just doing what you are already doing by reading a larger buffer.